# Integrate GWT with Spring Security with custom login page

Tags: gwt, spring-security

I have followed
http://krams915.blogspot.hk/2011/01/spring-and-gwt-security-via-spring.html
to build a GWT app with spring security with custom login page.

However, How can I handle the followings things?

1) If the user is not logged in, direct the user to login page, but not showing the HTTP ERROR page.

2) after the user is logged in, direct the user to front page or previous page but not /j_spring_security_check

I have tried replacing /j_spring_security_check in the loginpage.jsp to the /XXXEntry.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997. I can successfully redirect back to the GWT app, but it stills said that Authentication required.

Could anybody help? Better with code examples. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found another solutions for GWT and Spring Security integration:
http://www.site.lalitbhatt.com/spring-security-gwt-integration

this article make a login.html rather that jsp. Very easy to understand and implement.

Everthing works fine now.

Updated: The link moved to http://tech.lalitbhatt.net/2014/08/spring-security-gwt-integration.html